# Capture attribute id and use it to search in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML.

```
<root>
  <items>
     <item attr="value1" id="id1"> ... </item>
     <item attr="value2" id="id2"> ... </item>
  </items>
  <offers>
     <offer id="id1">
       <elem> someText </elem>
     </offer>
     <offer id="id2">
       <elem> someText </elem>
     </offer>
  </offers>
</root>
```

Is there a way to select- using XPath - the `elem` tag for the `item` whose `attr="value1"`?

Basically, I need to know if there is a way to *capture* the `id` value for the `item` and use it to find the corresponding `offer`.

I know I could simply use the `ids`. But I am building this XPath in runtime and I only know the value of `attr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for the `elem` which is a child of `offer` whose attribute `id` matches with the attribute `id` of `item` tag

The below xpath should give you that:

`//offers/offer[@id=(//item[@attr="value1"]/@id)]/elem`

It looks for the `offer` tags whose `id` attributes match for any `item` tags with the same attribute values and then return its `elem` tags.

If you want the text inside, just add `text()` at the end of xpath like :

`//offers/offer[@id=(//item[@attr="value1"]/@id)]/elem/text()`